# vuejs and laravel-vuejs doesnt see changes in components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I am new in vuejs and I am using vuejs in laravel 
this is working and showing component but after making refresh 
the page what can I do to see changes with out refreshing page?
these are what I have done
in Webpack:

> mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
>       .extract(['vue'])

in my html file:

```
<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script> 
 <script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>  
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

commands:
 npm run dev
npm run watch

Comment: show your code here

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: I think you are missing `BrowserSync`. It is a plugin that was included into `Laravel Mix` that you have to configure it yourself in `webpack.mix.js` to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run command into your terminal:

```
  npm install
  npm run dev
  npm run watch
```

and will see changes continuously :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn how to make **single page application (SPA)** which does not refresh the page but update the content according to the route. 
https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

You will have to learn [vue](https://vuejs.org/), [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) to make SPA. when you get some experience then learn [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) also.

Comment: no I am not asking about router in vue js I have a simple component that has a variable in data and I go to that componet and change that variable I expect the page be updated it self and show changes istead of refreshing that

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and struggled for a couple of days, the problem is the webpack mix configuration: this is what worked for me, but take care to remove the host in case you're not working with Laravel Homestead, if you are just leave it as it is and change the proxy value to your site local url.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.browserSync({
host: '192.168.10.10',
proxy: 'mysite.test',
open: false,
files: [
    'app/**/*.php',
    'resources/views/**/*.php',
    'resources/js/**/*.vue',
    'packages/mixdinternet/frontend/src/**/*.php',
    'public/js/**/*.js',
    'public/css/**/*.css'
],
watchOptions: {
    usePolling: true,
    interval: 500
}
});
```

Note: I think it was a sort of a bug in NMP, but the first time I tested this config, it it didn't work. What I did was to remove the polling part, ran
`npm watch-poll`, stop the watching and then added again the polling settings and ran simply `npm run watch` and workied like a charm!

**EDIT**

Btw, there is small issue with this config, you have to save twice for the browser to see the changes

Hope It helps!

-Hugo